# Adding second WPF Button to window after creating application-wide template corrupts the template

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I follow these steps and get an unexpected result:

1. Create a new Visual Basic WPF Application in either VS2015 or
   VS2017RC.
2. Double-click the Button in the Toolbox to add a Button to
   `MainWindow.xaml`.
3. Right-click the Button and choose "Edit Template / Edit a Copy..."
4. Select "Name (Key): Apply to all" and "Define in:Application," then
       click "OK."
5. Double-click the Button in the Toolbox to add a second Button to
       `MainWindow.xaml`.

The result is that, instead of a second Button, I get this error message:

**InvalidOperationException: Infinite loop in references found while processing the Template for an element named '' of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Button'.**

The `application.xaml` file appears to be corrupted when I do this, deleting the `ControlTemplate` `Triggers` and adding a `Button` to the template (which may be the reason the IDE complains of an infinite loop, as a `Button` now includes a `Button` in its own definition).

Is anyone else observing this? Is it a bug?